# How can I add a data label inside a pie chart?

Tags: reporting-services

Im creating a SSRS report and I would like to add total count label inside a pie chart. (29,351)

Is there any setting allow me doing this?

I tried add a empty test box and placed inside the pie chart but it failed(it will move to outside the chart)

Also I would like to add a line point to the chart, how do i do this as well?

[image]

So this is the expectation I would like to see.

Much thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built-in chart types (Doughnut, Pie etc.) you cannot add a text box that sits over the chart, and there is not option to fill the centre with text. The textbox, as you have already seen, will be rendered outside the chart object.

You can however display the values outside the chart and draw callout lines from the data labels.

To do this, add the data labels and then click the chart until you see "Chart Series" in the properties. Then set the `PieLabelStyle` property to "Outside" and the `PieLinecolor` property to whatever colour you like as below.

[image]